# Image() is already defined in class during Maven build using Lombok

Tags: java, maven, lombok

The below code is causing a compilation error (`Image() is already defined in class`) on the line with `@NoArgsConstructor` when building with Maven.

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

// tag::code[]
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Image {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Image(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

What is causing this problem and how can I fix it?

EDIT: Lombok version is 1.16.22.

Comment: Please, update the question with the version of Lombok. If it's 1.16.22, update to 1.18.0 - see e.g. [#1703 on GitHub](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1703).

Comment: Tomasz has now posted this as an answer. Answers should not be posted directly in the quetsion, so I'll edit and remove it. Feel free to mark Tomasz answer as accepted instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to a bug in Lombok v1.16.22, specifying both `@Data` and `@NoArgsConstructor` on a class triggered an error. This has been fixed in major release v1.18.0.

In the [Lombok changelog](https://projectlombok.org/changelog), we find the following under v1.18.0:

> BUGFIX: Do not generate a private no-args constructor if that breaks the code. [Issue #1703](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1703), [Issue #1704](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1704), [Issue #1712](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1712)