# gradle build failing - possible lombok issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lombok

I've installed lombok 1.18.4 for STS.

However, if I try to build my jar in the terminal with `./gradlew clean build` rather than through STS I get this error:

```
Task :compileJava FAILED
Image.java:12: error: constructor Image() is already defined in class Image
@NoArgsConstructor
^
1 error
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51202966/image-is-already-defined-in-class-during-maven-build-using-lombok) page which suggests it's an issue with an older version of lombok. As I seem to have it installed and working through the IDE, is there anything I must do to get this to build in the terminal?

Here is my `Image` class code:

```
package com.greglturnquist.learningspringboot.learningspringboot;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

//tag::code[]
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Image {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Image(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

}
//end::code[]
```

Comment: can you update `Image` class code?

Comment: probably you have already defined a default no arg Image constructor, so you should remove it if you're using @NoArgsConstructor

Comment: Apologies. Code updated.

Comment: What version of Lombok is defined in your Gradle dependencies? That's the version of the annotation processor that would be used for a command line build, as far as I know.

Comment: Actually, it seems to be 1.16.22 which I believe is the problem version. How do I update dependency versions in Gradle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment about the Gradle version, look for the `build.gradle` file for your project.

Find the dependencies section within, and update the line related to lombok to match your STS version

You should see a line similar to this, but with 1.16.22 as the version.

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4')
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to edit the code sample you provided but your suggestion worked a treat.

Comment: Feel free to suggest an edit to the answer so it's more correct.

Answer (score 5):

Add following as dependencies

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'
```

and repository

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the `AccessLevel` i'm just going through this issue in github [here](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1703)

```
@NoArgsConstructor(access=AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
```

**Github Resource** From the refered link

> Yes, this is a bug. Sorry. Will see how soon we can make a new release.
>
> 1.16.22 constructor has private access #1704

**OR update to**

> Update Lombok dependency version to 1.18.2 #14127

Answer (score 0):

try this, it works for me

```
compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
```